# LinkedIn API не видит мои домены

Tags: linkedin, linkedin-api

Всем привет.
При аутентификации в API LinkedIn через Javascript постоянно получаю ошибку: "You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration." Перечитал кучу форумов, проверил все настройки, добавил 5 разных доменов включая локальный (http://localhost), но проблема осталась. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.
Мой Javascript:

```js
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
        api_key: Client_ID
        onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
     authorize: true
    </script>   
    
<script>
 function onLinkedInLoad() {
  IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", onLinkedInAuth);
 }
  
 function onLinkedInAuth() {
  IN.API.Profile("me").fields("firstName", "lastName", "publicProfileUrl", "pictureUrl", "summary", "headline").result(displayProfiles);
 };
 
 function displayProfiles(profiles) {
      console.log(profiles.values[0]);
 }
            
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#linkedin').click(function() {
   if (!IN.User.isAuthorized()) {
        IN.User.authorize(function() {
            onLinkedInAuth();
        });
   }
   else
   {
   onLinkedInAuth();
   }
   return false;
  });
 })
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Пробовал всё - результатов 0. Приблизительно через сутки ошибка исчезла сама и приложение заработало на всех доменах.